# Is it possible to use both ERC721 and ERC1155 standards in the same staking contract?

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, erc-1155

Is it possible to use both ERC721 and ERC1155 standards in the same staking contract, or would that require 2 separate contracts?

Comment: I have tried many approaches to get this to work, but no success. Even though I successfully corrected the event Declaration error, I couldn't get it to work. I don't think that the both ERCs are created to work in the same contract for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically, why not.

You may need to implement some parts twice, with weird if/else statements. But some parts you can keep common.

Another, perhaps more important questions is *whether you should use the same contract or not*. There is no correct answer to that question. I would probably implement them separately to keep the contract(s) as small as possible, but possibly share some common functionality (via inheritance, for example).

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to do this right now and I am getting DeclarationError:

"error[5883]: DeclarationError: Event with same name and parameter types defined twice.
--> lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol:25:5:
|
25 |     event ApprovalForAll(address indexed owner, address indexed operator, bool approved);
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: Other declaration is here:
--> lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC1155/IERC1155.sol:36:5:
|
36 |     event ApprovalForAll(address indexed account, address indexed operator, bool approved);
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
"

I will try to work through this and post the result.